# MacOS - sending sound over bluetooth and video over HDMI at the same time?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, video, bluetooth, hdmi

I've been using my 13" 2015 MacBook Pro with BenQ projector. I'm connecting these with simple HDMI and watching Netflix, that's all, no Apple TV, no fancy stuff.

Right now my projector is connected to 5.1 home theater but I need something more mobile and I've been thinking about a bluetooth soundbar, [something like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013WVVNUY).

My question is, will watching movies using HDMI cable and streaming audio using bluetooth at the same time work? It will look something like this:

```
Macbook <===== HDMI CABLE (VIDEO ONLY) =====> Projector
Macbook <===== BLUETOOTH (AUDIO ONLY) =====> Soundbar
```

Has anyone tried it?